# 'torah-reading' and 'laining' tags

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

We've had the [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading) tag for a while, and it's included all sorts of questions about the Torah reading. Then someone asked [a question about reading *Nach* with the cantillation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34614), and, presumably because it's not about Torah reading — "Torah" in that phrase typically means *chamisha chumshe Tora* — tagged it [laining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laining) instead.

Unfortunately, many of the [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading)-tagged questions could be tagged [laining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laining) too. The two tags mean almost the same thing.

I should have said or done something at the time.

Now, the [laining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laining) tag has [another question, this one about how to prepare a passage](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35862). It's not specifically about Torah reading — or any other book. So I guess the [torah-reading] tag is out. But having two such overlapping tags is silly.

**I propose that all questions currently tagged [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading) get tagged [laining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laining) instead.** (This goes against my usual dislike of using Yiddish, which is specifically Ashkenazic. I can't think of a better word for it that's both clearly about it (unlike [torah-service](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-service) or bare "reading") and broad enough to cover all its questions (unlike [trop-cantillation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trop-cantillation)).)

**Please upvote this question if you support my proposal and downvote it if you oppose my proposal**, and don't vote on it otherwise. Please post alternative proposals (for what to do with these two tags) as answers, below, so people may similarly vote on them.

(If we decide to retag all [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading)-tagged questions, a moderator can do this easily, quickly, and without 'bumping' the questions so they appear on the homepage.)

Comment: Why not [tag:tanach-reading] or better [tag:tanach-chanting] / [tag:chanting-tanach]

Comment: @DoubleAA, also possibly good ideas. Post an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [laining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laining) is a better primary tag for this context. However, I think that the existing [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading) tag should be maintained as a synonym for it, since Torah reading, per se, is a majority subset of laining, both in practice and in MY content, and because "Torah reading" is how many people would refer to the activity.

In addition, I think that the wikis for the [laining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laining) (=[torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading)) and [torah-service](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-service) tags should explain how they are different from each other, since people will sometimes use the terms "laining" or especially "Torah reading" to refer to the ceremony, as opposed to the technical discipline it depends on.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there should be one tag and not two.

To mitigate the Yiddishism just a bit, how about [chanting-leining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanting-leining)?  That at least uses an English word in the primary position, while still matching on the other.  (Since I just noticed that the current tag is "laining" rather than "leining", possibly we need to synonomize that.  Yay transliteration variations. :-) )